# minifying angular

Tags: angularjs, minify

I have this interest in automate/simplify angular project with a compiler tool, which might work on everything else, but angular inject and namespacing is awkward enough to escape compiler knowledge. What is the best/professional method for doing this?

thanks, just one last thing,

```
app.controller('ctrl',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    ...
}]);
```

works when minified, but how do I minify

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

}]);
```

and does it work when I minify successive actions?

```
app.controller(...).directive(...).run(...)
```

Comment: These should all work fine. Check out my build scripts: http://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate. But I'm not sure what you're specifically asking here. What's the problem you are encountering?

Comment: app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){$routeProvider.something()...}]); turns into                            app.config(['$routeProvider', function(e){e.f=function()...}                                             when minified, and causes e->eProvider errors. so am I missing something in this process? should I be using $injector or $inject somewhere in the app?

Comment: The code you provided works for me just fine - again, check out that link. Can you post the body of the function too?

Comment: ok, i will try it, is there anything else I need to be ware of after I've placed the line format of injection?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I've never had any issue with `config` minification.

Comment: also, i've seen threads on this one but i'm not sure i understand, how to handle html files that have ng-model or ng-show bounded to $scope.vars or even $scope.var.obj, wouldn't the vars or the obj be damaged eventually as we minify a 6000 line js file?

Comment: No, object properties are not usually minified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Angular, you need to annotate functions for the injector to know which dependencies you want to inject in your function. There are basically three ways to inject dependencies in your function which are being described on official angular website. The three ways are:

1.Use the inline array annotation

```
 yourModule.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
```

2.Use the $inject property annotation

```
var yourController = function($scope) {};

yourController.$inject = ['$scope'];

yourModule.controller('yourController', yourController);
```

3.Implictly from the function parameter names

```
yourModule.controller('yourController', function($scope) {});
```

Now when you minify your project, your dependencies names will get renamed. 
In first case your code will be like

```
yourModule.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function(e) {}]);
```

In third case your code will be like

```
yourModule.controller('yourController',  function(e) {});
```

It will break your app because angular has no way to recognize your dependency name. So it is advised never to use implicit dependency injection in your project. From the above two inline array annotation is the most popular way amongst programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate. It will allow you to write your code like follows.

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
});
```

and then ngAnnotate turns it into the following which is safe for minification.

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout",   function($scope, $timeout) {
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The minifyer leaves strings untouched, that's why we use the array notation.
Chaining methods wont change the way the minifyer keeps strings intact.

```
var app=module(myapp);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider.dosomestuffs()
}]);
```

will be minified in something like

```
var a=module(myapp);
a.config(['$routeProvider', function(b){
      b.dosomestuffs()
}]);
```

but angular will still find its way around thanks to the '$routeProvider' string.

Answer (score 0):

If you always use annotations there should not be problems minifying angular scripts.

```
app.controller(['$scope', function(mrScope) {
    mrScope.yourProperty = 'it does not matter the dependency variable names if you use annotations'; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the array notation for the dependencies you are injecting, no minification trouble is expected. The minification tool you are using should handle any of your examples without trouble (on my project we're using `uglify` to accomplish that).

In fact, for oddly named injections (named with dots and chars that result in invalid function names like `ABC.CDE`), the array notation is the best way to inject them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when minifying, and like you, it only failed for the `$routeProvider` config elements..  The answer for me was to use the `$inject` method like Himanshu says for my configs, even though the syntax you show for your first example works for my controllers.  So I'll post my `.config()` code here since I don't see it specifically listed in the answers above:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
var RouteProviderConfig = function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when(...)
            .otherwise(...);
    };
RouteProviderConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
app.config(RouteProviderConfig);
```

This fixed my error for configs, but my controllers work the way your first example is written:

```
app.controller('ctrl',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    ...
}]);
```

The [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification) seems to suggest that both ways should work, so I think it's possible there is a bug with configs, or `$routeProvider`, or something else entirely...